# Is there an FAA reference for rounding off of traffic pattern altitudes?

Tags: air-traffic-control, pilot-technique

The convention by default is to fly the downwind leg at 1000' above ground level, but most pilots cannot really discern or fly within just a few feet of a chosen altitude, and generally prefer to fly at altitudes in hundred foot increments.

So, for example at KPAE where the field elevation is published as 606' I would target 1600' MSL as a traffic pattern altitude, vs trying to hold exactly 1606'.

Is there is any written guidance from the FAA, regulatory or not, (i.e. AIM) that describes allowable rounding off?  Or, by a specific example such as I've shown above, it's implied that TPA is always the elevation to the exact foot, plus 1000'?

Comment: Might be a systems thing where autopilots and altitude bugs only have steps of 100 feet. I know flight plans are also similar with the 100s digit being the lowest unit you can enter.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann, just to clarify, I'm not asking about bug settings.

Comment: I doubt there is a reference but the only place it would be is the TERPS (FAA order 8260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out, the standard pattern altitude is 1000 ft. AGL. However, at certain airports the pattern altitude is not 1000 ft (see the example for KSQL airport below).

An exception is a regulatory requirement for Class D, C, and B airspace ([14 CFR's 91.129(e), 91.130(a) and 91.131(a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91#p-91.129(e)(1)) ), requiring turbojet aircraft to enter the traffic pattern at an altitude of at least 1500 ft. AGL (unless cloud clearance criteria requires a different altitude).

I cannot find a regulation or procedural guidance (e.g., AIM) that provides for rounding-off a pattern altitude.  Often, but not always, you can determine the pattern altitude by referring to the appropriate Chart Supplement. (It's always a good idea to check the Chart Supplement before going into or out of any airport).

Below, is an example of a Traffic Pattern Altitude (TPA) of **800 ft. AGL**, published in the Chart Supplement for San Carlos (KSQL) airport in California, that has a pattern altitude of **806 ft. MSL** with a field elevation of **6 ft. MSL**.

From this example, it appears that rounding-off is not used.

[image]

Comment: A weird one if you want to check it out is Ellensburg, KELN:  Field elevation 1763', TPA = 834' AGL or 2597' MSL.  Is there some valid reason you couldn't just make the TPA 837' AGL to let pilots fly it at 2600' MSL?!!!

Comment: Probably the same reason KSQL TPA is not 800 ft. MSL.

Comment: But at least the 800' AGL is a round number.

Comment: @MichaelHall - good point. It's a head-scratcher.

Comment: The regulatory requirement of Class D extends to Class C and Class B airports.  See 91.130(a) and 91.131(a).

Comment: @wbeard52 - good comment, I added that to my answer.

Comment: @MichaelHall if the TPA is 2597' AMSL, would it be a violation to fly at 2600' AMSL? It seems like that would be well within the margin of instrument error, and inconsequential considering that virtually all planes are at least three feet tall, meaning that even if you keep the center of your plane precisely at 2600, the top and bottom are each at least a couple feet off?

Comment: @Someone, no, you are correct.  It is also WELL inside typical airmanship standards expected of pilots.  And you can’t even really discern 3’ on an altimeter either, hence my question.